# Changing values in stores in Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to learn Vuex, and I'm stuck trying to make it possible so that the number value changes every time you click on the `p`-element, using the mutation called `changeNumber`. I also want to make the number value be shown in the `p`-element. This is my code so far but I'm stuck:

```
let object = {

}

let state = {
  object,
  someArray: [],
  someBool: true,
  counter: 0,
  someOtherValue: 'Text'
}

let changeNumber = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter += 1
  }
}

let store = new Vuex.Store({
  changeNumber,
  state
})

Vue.component('counter-button', {
  computed: {
    counter() {
      return this.$store.state.counter
    }
  },
  template: `<input :value="$store.state.counter" @click="$store.commit('increment')" type="button">`
})

Vue.component('some-component', {
  computed: {
    someOtherValue() {
      return this.$store.state.someOtherValue
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{ someOtherValue }}</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  template: '<some-component></some-component>',

})
```

Answer (score 2):

in `new Vuex.Store({options})`you can't add the function `changeNumber` as option.

check the [doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#vuex-store-constructor-options)
it should be inside `mutations`.

if you replace `changeNumber` with `mutations` your solution will work.

```
const mutations = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter += 1
  }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  mutations,
  state
})
```